# Words for computer: パソコン or コンピューター

Tags: word-choice, loanwords

What is the difference between パソコン vs コンピューター?

Comment: パソコン is thought to be an abbreviation for パーソナルコンピューター (personal computer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, what Faily Feely said [in comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39837/words-for-computer-%e3%83%91%e3%82%bd%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3-or-%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%94%e3%83%a5%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc#comment75500_39837) is all:

> パソコン is thought to be an abbreviation for パーソナルコンピューター (personal computer).

When used as パソコン, I'd imagine a (home) desktop PC.

When used as コンピューター, its meaning is generally the same as English *computer*, I suppose.

Comment: This "PC" includes Mac and Linux etc., for those might find it ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

パソコン or "PC" is Japanese abbreviation of personal computer. Your notebook and desktop computer are パソコン.

コンピュータ refers to electronic computor in general which ranges from desktop business-use computors to super highspeed computors that perform quadrillion digit culcuration in a second.